# Is there a classical harmonic oscillator system with a discrete set of modes?

Tags: classical-mechanics, harmonic-oscillator

For a free rope arbitrary wavelengths are allowed. But if we fix a rope at two ends only a discrete set of *wavelengths* is allowed.

[image]

Is there are similar way to modify a harmonic oscillator such that only a discrete set of *energies* (amplitudes) is allowed?

---

(Picture By Adjwilley, CC BY-SA 3.0, 
https://commons.wikimedia.org/w/index.php?curid=26249625)

Comment: I'm unclear of exactly what you want: a single harmonic oscillator has only one 'mode' so that constitutes a discrete set. The fixed endpoint wave example you give is also a discrete (if infinite) set of modes.

Comment: To amplify the above comment, the string is but the infinite set of coupled oscillators, whose normal modes in your display are but the single modes of the decoupled oscillators in momentum space: read up on your continuum mechanics text, e.g. Fetter & Walecka, *Theoretical Mechanics of Particles and Continua*, § 7.40.

Comment: @jacob1729  you're both right. For the fixed rope there is a discrete spectrum of wave lengths. What I'm looking for is a mechanical system for which the frequency spectrum of a harmonic oscillator is discrete.

Comment: @CosmasZachos I edited to question to clarify what I'm asking for

Comment: The classical *frequency spectrum*, ***not*** energy spectrum, for a single oscillator is discrete, fixed at a characteristic frequency. All systems described by one such oscillator follow suit. Surely you are not calling energy profiles classical spectra?

Comment: @CosmasZachos my bad, thanks! I meant the energy/amplitude and not the frequency.

Comment: NO, for any system described by *just* the single classical harmonic oscillator, the energy is continuous. That is what "quantum" contrasts to when you get there.